# Using flash xml setting in php

Tags: php, xml, flash, rss, feed

Hi I used a flash template for my web site and I'd like to make a php version out of it. It's a portfolio so I would like to update only one file when I post a new picture. The file that my flash version uses is an xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<illustrations>
<!-- item style -->
<style>
    <!-- show width/height -->
    <itemwidth>250</itemwidth>
    <itemheight>130</itemheight>
</style>

<!-- gallery items -->
<items>
        <item title='Hot-swap' date="14/06/2014" src='assets/illustrations/thms1.jpg'     path='assets/illustrations/big1.jpg'>
<![CDATA[<font size="10" face="Arial" color="#71c9f1"><br/></font>]]>
</item>
</items>
</illustrations>
```

I've tried to find how but I lack of knowledge in that domain, the only thing I found is that code:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("xmlsetting\illustrations_config.xml");
print_r($xml);
?>
```

but it says that when I run it on my webpage:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load    external entity "xmlsetting\illustrations_config.xml" in /home/a3754461/public_html/index.php on line    2"
```

Thanks

Comment: is that a typo? `xmlsetting<backslash>illustrations_config.xml`? maybe forward slash `/`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is thanks, I get this now:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [comment] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) [style] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [comment] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [itemwidth] => 250 [itemheight] => 130 ) [items] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [item] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [title] => Hot-swap [date] => 14/06/2014 [src] => assets/illustrations/thms1.jpg [path] => assets/illustrations/big1.jpg ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [title] => Oyez! [date] => 26/11/2012 [src] => assets/illustrations/thms2.jpg [path] => assets/illustrations/big2.jpg ) ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [title] => Ancienne Mars [date] => 15/01/2009 [src] => assets/illustrations/thms3.jpg [path] => assets/illustrations/big3.jpg ) ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [title] => Throne room [date] => 16/03/2012 [src] => assets/illustrations/thms4.jpg [path] => assets/illustrations/big4.jpg ) ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [title] => Pingu [date] => 19/12/2008 [src] => assets/illustrations/thms5.jpg [path] => assets/illustrations/big5.jpg ) ) [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [title] => Revolution [date] => 23/07/2014 [src] => assets/illustrations/thms6.jpg [path] => assets/illustrations/big6.jpg ) ) [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [title] => Megadeth [date] => 13/02/2006 [src] => assets/illustrations/thms7.jpg [path] => assets/illustrations/big7.jpg ) ) [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [title] => Sous projecteurs [date] => 21/02/2007 [src] => assets/illustrations/thms8.jpg [path] => assets/illustrations/big8.jpg ) ) [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [title] => Cube [date] => 21/02/2007 [src] => assets/illustrations/thms9.jpg [path] => assets/illustrations/big9.jpg ) ) [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [title] => Pour Caroline Senecal [date] => 15/02/2014 [src] => assets/illustrations/thms10.jpg [path] => assets/illustrations/big10.jpg ) ) [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [title] => Etiquette [date] => 13/03/2012 [src] => assets/illustrations/thms11.jpg [path] => assets/illustrations/big11.jpg ) ) [11] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [title] => Ajna [date] => 14/03/2012 [src] => assets/illustrations/thms12.jpg [path] => assets/illustrations/big12.jpg ) ) ) ) )
```

But I just saw something interresting, could I use flickr put my pictures on it and use their rss feed to fill my gallery on my web page? And then could I put my flickr rss feed on every related art community? I would only need to upload via flicker?

Comment: ok flickr is only for photodraphy, I could create my own rss feed instead.